# Track phone data usage from PC

Tags: android, data

I manage my companies cell phones on a shared account.  We allot a certain amount of data to each user each month.  They are contractually obligated to this amount, else they are responsible for overages.  I am looking for a way to be automatically alerted via email whenever any one user exceeds their allotted data.  It would preferably be a third party software approved by Verizon or an app that sends the email.  If anyone knows of anything useful, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if I could download the billing information in CSV.  These records could be imported into a database.

```
Select sum(minutes)-400,* from phones where sum(minutes)>400 group by phone_number,month(date),year(date)
```

Where 400 is the allowable number of free minutes.
Your going to store the date and time in a single column so the month() function exacts the month from the date/time column.  The same thing for the year.

Then your need a table containing:

1. The account or phone number of each company phone
2. Call date (and time is nice)
3. Duration
4. You probably want the destination phone number just for record keeping purposes, but not really needed.

Anyone who uses less than the approved 400 minutes won't show up on the report because we asked for greater than 400 minutes.